# create remmember me cookie with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

hello this is my first project and after alot of searching i cant set cookie
please help me there are my codes what should i have to add into it?

it is create user table

```
        php :        
        "CREATE TABLE `users` (
              `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
              `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
              `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
              `permission` enum('user','admin') COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
              `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
              `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
              UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci;",
```

class auth contains function login logout , checkadmin and register

```
        php:
          <?php
                namespace AdminDashboard;
    
              require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/DataBase.php"));
              use DataBase\DataBase;
    
            class Auth
            {
         function __construct()
        {
            if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
                session_start();
            }
        }
    
        public function login()
        {
            require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../template/auth/login.php"));
        }
        public function checkLogin($request)
        {
            if (empty($request['email']) || empty($request['password'])) {
                $this->redirectBack();
            } else {
                $db = new DataBase();
                $user = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`email` = ?); ",        [$request['email']])->fetch();
                if ($user != null) {
                    if (password_verify($request['password'], $user['password'])) {
                        $_SESSION['user'] = $user['id'];
                        $this->redirect('admin');
                    } else {
                        $this->redirectBack();
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->redirectBack();
                }
            }
        }
        public function register()
        {
            require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../template/auth/register.php"));
        }
        public function registerStore($request)
        {
    
            if (empty($request['email']) || empty($request['password'])) {
                $this->redirectBack();
            } else if (strlen($request['password'] < 8)) {
                $this->redirectBack();
            } else if (!filter_var($request['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $this->redirectBack();
            } else {
                $db = new DataBase();
                $user = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`email` = ?); ", [$request['email']])->fetch();
                if ($user != null) {
                    $this->redirectBack();
                } else {
                    $request['password'] = $this->hash($request['password']);
                    $db->insert('users', array_keys($request), $request);
                    $this->redirect('login');
                }
            }
        }
    
        public function logout()
        {
            if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
                unset($_SESSION['user']);
                session_destroy();
            }
            $this->redirectBack();
        }
    
        public function checkAdmin()
        {
            if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
                $db = new DataBase();
                $user = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ? ; ", [$_SESSION['user']])->fetch();
                if ($user != null) {
                    if ($user['permission'] != 'admin') {
                        $this->redirect('home');
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->redirect('home');
                }
            } else {
                $this->redirect('home');
            }
        }
    
    
        protected function redirect($url)
        {
            $prtocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], 'https') === true ? 'https://' : 'http://';
            header("Location: " . $prtocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/admin-panel/" . $url);
        }
    
    
        protected function redirectBack()
        {
            header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        }
    
        public function hash($string){
            $hashString= password_hash($string,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            return $hashString;
        }
          }
```

user.class

```
<?php
namespace AdminDashboard;
require_once ("Admin.class.php");
 require_once (realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/DataBase.php"));
 use DataBase\DataBase;

 class User extends Admin{

    public function index(){
        $db= new DataBase();
        $users=$db->select('SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `id` DESC ;');
        require_once (realpath(dirname(__FILE__). "/../template/admin/users/index.php"));
    }

    public function permission($id){
        $db= new DataBase();
        $user = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`id` = ?); ",[$id])->fetch();
        if($user['permission'] == 'admin'){
            $db->update('users',$id,['permission'],['user']);

        }
        else{
            $db->update('users',$id,['permission'],['admin']);

        }
        $this->redirectBack();

    }

    public function edit($id){
        $db= new DataBase();
        $user = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ? ;", [$id])->fetch();
        require_once (realpath(dirname(__FILE__). "/../template/admin/users/edit.php"));

    }

    public function update($request,$id){
        $db= new DataBase();
        $db->update('users',$id,array_keys($request),$request);
        $this->redirect('user');
    }

    public function delete($id){
        $db= new DataBase();
        $db->delete('users',$id);
        $this->redirectBack();
    }


 }
```

html: it is login form

```
    <body>
         
                <form method="post" class="" action="http://localhost/admin-panel/check-login">
                    <?php
                    $httpReferer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null;
                    if($httpReferer == 'http://localhost/admin-panel/login'){?>
                    <div> <small class="form-text text-danger"> user is wrong</small> </div><?php
                    }?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email ...">
                        <!--            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password ...">
                        <!--            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>-->
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">login</button>
                </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

please help me what should i do?
?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: What is the problem while setting cookie ? Use setcookie() php function

Comment: i dont know any thing about cookie and if is possible please add the codes about remmember me

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_network_setcookie.asp follow this link

Comment: thank you but how can i use cookie for login and remmember  me?  can you wrote the hole codes and send it to me please

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://phppot.com/php/secure-remember-me-for-login-using-php-session-and-cookies/&ved=2ahUKEwi5xfGv-_TtAhWDxDgGHYidD1UQFjADegQIDRAB&usg=AOvVaw0UBhHQjE7UYKTl4woLEQnK&cshid=1609305828859 follow this link and code, everything you are seeking is mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setcookie()` function in the login function of your Auth class or in the login file that you have included.

Comment: Heloo Aavatto, welcome to stack overflow, please read this link to know how to make a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: can you send the hole codes with setcokie() please